# Use an image in WPF InkCanvas

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

I would like to import an image into  a WPF inkcanvas object, specifically into the strokes collection, not into the children collection and not as a background image. The rational for this is I want to be able to easily erase and manipulate on the drawing as if it was originally drawn in inkcanvas.

I have seen articles on exporting the strokes to XAML and converting strokes to paths. Perhaps there is a way to convert a bitmap to a path and import it into the stroke collection?

Comment: Do you mean on-the-fly vectorizing?

Comment: Not necessary on the fly. They could be preconverted and imported into an inkcanvas control The image could be SVG, or an SVG in a WPF canvas. What I am currently trying is to pull the path out of the canvas and convert it to stylepoints for the inkcanvas. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm currently looking for the same functionality...